# Hibernate LazyInitializingException

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

For example, I have 2 classes. The first

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_address_id")
    private Address address;

    //setters and getters
}
```

And the second:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    //setters and getters
}
```

So if I wand read `Employee` from database, I read `address` field. `Address` have `employeeList` with LazyInitializingException. **But I don't want to know `employeeList`**. I wanna know only `employee.getAddress()`.
I wand to send JSON object `Employee`. But at the client-side I have `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` by reason of LazyInitializingException .

May I use:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.itechart.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!-- USE--!>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- END USE--!>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Both of your classes have same name and mapped to same table. Is that correct?

Comment: @sam_eera! Oh, sorry! I correct

Comment: What do you mean by "Address have employeeList with LazyInitializingException". Did you mean employeeList in address is lazily initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSON` mapper might access `Address.employeeList` after `hibernate` session is closed. That is why it sends `LazyInitializingException`.

You can try any of the below solutions to solve the issue.

1 ) Exclude `employeeList` from the `JSON` mapping

In `Jackson` we can do it adding `@JsonIgnore`

```
@JsonIgnore
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
}
```

2 ) Initialize `employeeList` before send it to the `JSON` mapper.

You can do it by calling `employeeList.size()` method

3 ) You can change the fetchType to eager like below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
private List<Employee> employeeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during the JSON mapping it will walk through all the properties and try to access `Address.employeeList`. When it does you obviuosly are no longer in a Hibernate Session and hence the exception.

Either exclude `employeeList` from the JSON mapping (clean solution) or initialize `employeeList` before the session is terminated by changing the fetch type of the `OneToMany` to `EAGER` or explicitly initializing the collection (= quick and dirty).

My preferred solution to avoid issues like this is not to pass entities to the frontend code but always map them to TO's (Transfer Objects).